# 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-2: someemail@gmail.com

Tags: amazon-web-services

This question has been asked at other places but the answers don't solve my problem. I am doing testing and am sending email to a fictitious email id. When I send the email, I get error `554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-2: someemail@gmail.com`

My account is not in sandbox and the `from` email id is verified. Later I changed the email to a valid `gmail` id (a `to` email id which is not confirmed) and I get error `error in handling user signup transaction org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:587, com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-2: m****.****a@gmail.com`

I can't confirm `to` email ids as they would be of new users. How do I solve the problem? I am on basic plan on `aws` which I suppose means that I can't ask their technical support for help.

The `from` email id has been verified in the right region.

UPDATE
The problem could be that I am using `us-east-2` `smtp` endpoint but my account is still in `sandbox` in that region. I didn't realise this and got the `east-2` region out of `sandbox`. I have not submitted request to move the `us-east-2` out of sandbox. I'll update on status once that is done.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the region of smtp server which I was using still was in sandbox. I didn't know that the smtp account should be in production for the smtp dns being used. So if you are using smtp dns for London (EU West 2) (eg smtp.eu-west-2.aws...), ensure that the London (EU West 2) account is in production. Each region also has its own IAM credentials so create credentials for the right region.